# Discord Slash Command options not working

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a slash command in discord.

```
import discord
import datetime
import pickle
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dislash import *

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")
inter_client = InteractionClient(bot, test_guilds=[345328981039382528])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Nick ist online!")

@inter_client.slash_command(
    name="kick", # Defaults to the function name
    description="kick a user",
    guild_ids=[345328981039382528],
    options=[
        create_option(
            name="user",
            description="Choose a user",
            option_type=6,
            required=True
        )
    ]
)
async def kick(inter, user:str):
    pass

bot.run("-")
```

If i am trying to run it it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 20, in <module>
    create_option(
NameError: name 'create_option' is not defined
```

So someone said i should add the following line:

```
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
```

But this does not help. After adding this it says:

```
  line 7, in <module>
    from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
ModulNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'
```

However if i go to cmd and do:

```
pip install discord-py-slash-command
```

It says its already installed.
Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? Thanks for helping

Comment: When I first started developing slash commands I was also using dislash. It is no longer supported. I recommend switching to disnake.
https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
options=[
    Option("user","Choose a user", OptionType.USER)
]
```

Try changing your options in the slash command to as follows.

Comment: Even though I recommend disnake, I was able to figure out your dislash concern.